# joomla! article crashes when using @ character

Tags: joomla

Hello im having this issue. When i use the @ character in some joomla! article the browser crashes and doesnt show the content correctly. Just shows this:

[image]

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using? What version of Firefox are you using? Have you tested on other browsers? Are you getting any errors at all on the error log or console?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this problem is caused by a system/content plugin. Disable your 3rd party Joomla plugins one by one until the problem is resolved. Once you find out which plugin it is - try having it fixed.

Comment: Actually i did what @itoctopus suggested with no luck :(